# Orchard custom forms validation shows one field error per one field

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8

Is there an option or something to show all forms errors at once in orchard?

If I have three required text fields and all fields are empty:
It will only show field1 is mandatory

If I add something in field1
It will only show field2 is mandatory

How to have all three errors at once?

Comment: Before submitting or after? e.g. client side or server side?

Comment: After submitting with server errors please.

Comment: Somewhere it should say `@Html.ValidationSummary()` in your view to view all validation errors

Comment: I have this in my view, but it only shows the first error